# Need and impossibility of having a type of a signature

Tags: types, module, ocaml, signature

I have defined 2 signature and 4 modules as follows, and it works fine:

```
module type TRIANGLE =
  sig
    type 'a t
    val get ...
    val set ...
    ...
  end

module type MATRIX =
  sig
    type 'a t
    val unionArrayArray: 'a TriangleArray.t -> 'a TriangleArray.t -> 'a t
    val unionListList: 'a TriangleList.t -> 'a TriangleList.t -> 'a t
    val unionArrayList: 'a TriangleArray.t -> 'a TriangleList.t -> 'a t
    val unionListArray: 'a TriangleList.t -> 'a TriangleArray.t -> 'a t
    ...
  end

module rec MatrixArray: MATRIX =
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a array array
    ...
  end

and MatrixList: MATRIX =
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a list list
    ...
  end

and TriangleArray: TRIANGLE =
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a array array
    ...
  end

and TriangleList: TRIANGLE =
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a list list
    ...
  end
```

`TRIANGLE` and `MATRIX` are two parallel signatures. The function `unionXXXX` takes two right triangles, if their sides have same length, builds a matrix.

The module `XXXXArray` is internally realized by array of array, and the module `XXXXList` is internally realized by list of list. But they could have same signature `XXXX` which includes such functions as `set`, `get`...

The problem of this design is that, with the functions like `set`, `get` of `TRIANGLE`, 4 `unionXXXX` functions can have same implementation. We just need one function `union`, and its type is actually `: 'a TRIANGLE.t -> 'a TRIANGLE.t -> 'a MATRIX.t`.

But if I define the signature `MATRIX` as follows, the compiler stops at the signature of `union` and gives an `Error: Unbound module Triangle`:

```
module type TRIANGLE =
  sig
    type 'a t
    val get ...
    val set ...
    ...
  end

module type MATRIX =
  sig
    type 'a t
    val union: 'a TRIANGLE.t -> 'a TRIANGLE.t -> 'a t
    ...
  end
```

I hope I have shown it is better to combine 4 `unionXXXX` functions to one `union`, but it is really a pity that we can't specify its type, because of the lack of `'a TRIANGLE.t`, either in the signature `MATRIX` or in the modules `MatrixXXXX`.

I hope my need and concern has been clearly described, and does anyone have a solution or a better design?

**Edit1** : change case of letters as the comment suggests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a word on conventions : it's usually expected that module names have `CamelCase` formatting and module type names have `ALL_UPPERCASE` formatting. It took me two reads to notice you were dealing with module types instead of modules.

So, what you are trying to say here is that any module which implements module type `MATRIX` should be able, for *any* module `Triangle` that implements `TRIANGLE`, provide this signature:

```
type 'a t
val union : 'a Triangle.t -> 'a Triangle.t -> 'a t
```

It's not possible to express universal quantifiers like that. What you should do is use an existential quantifier and a functor :

```
module type MATRIX = sig
  module Triangle : TRIANGLE 
  type 'a t 
  val union : 'a Triangle.t -> 'a Triangle.t -> 'a t
end

module MatrixOfTriangle = functor (Triangle:TRIANGLE) -> struct
  module Triangle = Triangle
  type 'a t = ...
  let union t1 t2 = ...
end
```

This does force you to specify what triangle you are working on at any given point in your code, but you can use functors with `TRIANGLE` arguments to avoid settling on one type of triangle.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I guess `module type MatrixOfTriangle` should be `module MatrixOfTriangle`?

Comment: "but you can use functors with TRIANGLE arguments to avoid settling on one type of triangle." ==> What do you mean by that? It does not seem we can write `module M = MatrixOfTriangle(TRIANGLE)`

Comment: Actually, I also have other functions, for instance `split: 'a Matrix.t -> 'a Triangle.t * 'a Triangle`. That is why I define `MatrixXXXX` and `TriangleXXXX` recursively. If I follow your approach, it is better to also add `module Matrix: MATRIX` within `TRIANGLE`. Do you know how to do that? I have post this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058598/define-recursive-signatures-for-modules)

Comment: You need to define a `Triangle` module that implements `TRIANGLE`, and write `module M = MatrixOfTriangle(Triangle)`. If you have more functions, add them to `MATRIX` and define them in `MatrixOfTriangle`.

Comment: I have followed your approach, still got an error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082514/a-functor-including-an-inheritance-of-modules-does-not-work), could you please take a look?