# Define recursive signatures for modules

Tags: types, module, ocaml, signature

I know that it is possible to define recursive modules, does anyone know how to define recursive signatures? For instance, I would like to realize:

```
module type AAA = sig
  module Bbb : BBB
  type 'a t 
  val f : 'a Bbb.t -> 'a t
end

module type BBB = sig
  module Aaa : AAA
  type 'a t 
  val g : 'a Aaa.t -> 'a t
end
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, as far as I can tell. The closest solution is to limit the "recursive" bits to what is actually needed to express each signature separately:

```
module type AA =
sig
  module B : sig type t end
  type t
  val f : unit -> B.t
end

module type BB =
sig
  module A : sig type t end
  type t
  val g : unit -> A.t
end
```

And then refine when you define the modules:

```
module rec A : AA with module B = B =
struct
  module B = B
  type t = int
  let f () = B.g ()
end
and B : BB with module A = A =
struct
  module A = A
  type t = int
  let g () = A.f ()
end
```

FWIW, one might think that it should be possible to express recursive signatures (with much repetition) by using recursive modules:

```
module rec AA :
sig
  module type T = sig module B : BB.T end
end =
struct
  module type T = sig module B : BB.T end
end
and BB :
sig
  module type T = sig module A : AA.T end
end =
struct
  module type T = sig module A : AA.T end
end
```

However, that does not work:

```
Error: Unbound module type BB.T
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... `the closest solution is to limit the "recursive" bits` ==> Could you please elaborate more about the limits of your solution?

Comment: Well, this doesn't allow you to express arbitrary recursion between signatures, because you need to be able to isolate a self-contained subset of each signature as a kind of forward declaration. Also, you are repeating each of those subsets in two places -- but naming and `include`-ing them can help there. In my reply I didn't bother to do that, because the relevant subsets (type t) are small enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like that :

```
module rec Aaa : sig
  type 'a t 
  val f : 'a Bbb.t -> 'a t
end = Aaa
and Bbb : sig
  type 'a t
  val g : 'a Aaa.t -> 'a t
end = Bbb
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I really want to give a name to the signature, for instance, `AAA` aor `BBB`... you did not mention that in your answer...