# A functor including an inheritance of modules does not work

Tags: inheritance, types, module, ocaml

I am still struggling with my design and implementation of modules, I have defined the following:

```
module type MATRIX =
sig
  type 'a t
  val init: 'a -> 'a t
  val print: 'a t -> unit
end

module type MMM =
sig
  type 'a t
end

module type AMATRIX =
sig
  include MATRIX
  module Mmm : MMM
  module Matrix: MATRIX
  val matrix_of_amatrix: 'a t -> int -> int -> 'a Matrix.t
end

module MatrixArray: MATRIX =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
  let init (e: 'a) : 'a t = failwith "to do"
  let print (x: 'a t) : unit = failwith "to do"
end

module MmmArray: MMM =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
end
```

And a functor with an inheritance of modules:

```
module AMatrixArrayFun: functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> AMATRIX =
  functor (Mmm: MMM) ->
    functor (Matrix: MATRIX) ->
struct
  include MatrixArray
  module Mmm = Mmm
  module Matrix = Matrix

  let matrix_of_amatrix (m: 'a t) (nr_i: int) (nc_i: int) : 'a Matrix.t = failwith "to do"
end

module AMatrixArray = AMatrixArrayFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray)

let () =  MatrixArray.print (AMatrixArray.matrix_of_amatrix (AMatrixArray.init 5) 0 0)
```

The compilation stop at the last line, and gives an error:

```
Error: This expression has type
         int AMatrixArray.Matrix.t =
           int AMatrixArrayFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray).Matrix.t
       but an expression was expected of type 'a MatrixArray.t
```

So it seems that the compiler does not recognize that `int AMatrixArrayFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray).Matrix.t` is actually `'a MatrixArray.t`, but this is exactly what a functor is meant to do, right? Maybe it is the inheritance of modules which complicates the thing?

Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you elaborate more of what goal you are trying to achieve? That is not the first question you are asking about this topic, and I guess your problem is more a design issue at the first place.

Comment: Drive-by comment: "module AMatrixArrayFun: functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> AMATRIX = functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> ..." can be written more economically as "module AMatrixArrayFun (Mmm: MMM) (Matrix: MATRIX) : AMATRIX = ...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have coerced the signature of your `AMatrixArrayFun` functor to be:

```
functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> AMATRIX
```

Writing this eliminates any type relationships between the returned modules and the `Mmm` and `Matrix` argument. OCaml is only allowed to known that it's an `AMATRIX`, but not that its `Matrix` submodule was actually the `Matrix` module passed as a functor argument.

You need to add this information to the functor signature :

```
functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> 
  AMATRIX with module Mmm = Mmm and  module Matrix = Matrix
```